# program to remove vowels from a user input and diplay the remaining alphabets in alphabetic order in java

Tags: java

Please help me with the full code modified by someone again. I have tried, but error is coming as `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`. I am able to enter just the input from the user.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;  
import java.io.IOException;  
import java.io.InputStreamReader;  

public class RemoveVowels{  
    public static void main(String []args) {  
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));  
        System.out.println("Sample Program to Remove Vowels");  
        System.out.println("from a given string \n");  
        System.out.println("Enter a words : ");  
        String s = in.readLine();      
        System.out.println("\n" + "String with Vowels removed : ");  
        String r = removeVowels(s);  
        System.out.println(r);  
    } 

    private static String removeVowels(String s) {  
        String finalString = "";  
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {      
            if(!isVowel(Character.toLowerCase(s.charAt(i)))) {  
                finalString = finalString + s.charAt(i);  
            }  
        }  
        return finalString;  
    }  

    private static boolean isVowel(char c) {  
        String vowels = "aeiou";   
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {   
            if(c == vowels.charAt(i))  
                return true;  
        }  
        return false;     
    }  
}
```

Comment: Add that information to your question and indicate which is line 10.

Comment: Sample Input:
shriram

Sample Output:
hmrrs

Comment: Again, add this information to your question.

Comment: please post the stacktrace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add throws declaration to the method:

```
public static void main(String []args) throws IOException
```

or surround the code with try/catch:

```
try
{
    s = in.readLine();
} 
catch (IOException e)
{
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You haven't included in your code to sort the string alphabetically, you can do that as follows:

```
 private static String ascending(String s) 
    {
        char[] asc = s.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(asc);
        String sorted = new String(asc);
        return sorted;
    }
```

Complete code:

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;  
import java.io.IOException;  
import java.io.InputStreamReader;  
import java.util.Arrays;
public class RemoveVowels{  
    public static void main(String []args) throws IOException
    {  
        BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));  
        System.out.println("Sample Program to Remove Vowels from a given string \n");  
        System.out.println("Enter a line : ");  
        String s=in.readLine();      
        System.out.println("\n" + "String with Vowels removed : ");  
        String r=removeVowels(s);  
        System.out.println(r);  
    }  
    private static String removeVowels(String s)
    {  
        String finalString="";  
        for(int i=0;i<s.length(); i++) 
        {      
            if(!isVowel(Character.toLowerCase(s.charAt(i))))  
            {  
                finalString=finalString+s.charAt(i);  
            }  
        }  
        finalString= ascending(finalString);
        return finalString;  
    }  
    private static String ascending(String s) 
    {
        char[] asc = s.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(asc);
        String sorted = new String(asc);
        return sorted;
    }
    private static boolean isVowel(char c) 
    {  
        String vowels="aeiou";   
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++)  
        {   
            if(c==vowels.charAt(i))  
            return true;  
        }  
        return false;     
    }  
}
```

Comment: What's obvious to you may not be obvious to a new coder.

Comment: @thumbtackthief Removed.

Answer (score 0):

The output is

```
Sample Program to Remove Vowels
from a given string 

Enter a words : 
astalavista baby

String with Vowels removed :
stlvst bby
```

Here is your updated code, you were missing the try catch statement:

```
package removevowels;

import java.io.BufferedReader;  
import java.io.IOException;  
import java.io.InputStreamReader;  

public class RemoveVowels {  
    public static void main(String []args) {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));  

        try { 
            System.out.println("Sample Program to Remove Vowels");  
            System.out.println("from a given string \n");  
            System.out.println("Enter a words : ");  
            String s = in.readLine();      
            System.out.println("\n" + "String with Vowels removed : ");  
            String r = removeVowels(s);  
            System.out.println(r);  
        }
        catch (IOException ed){} 
    }

    private static String removeVowels(String s) {  
        String finalString = "";  
        for (int i = 0;i < s.length(); i++) {      
            if (!isVowel(Character.toLowerCase(s.charAt(i)))) {  
                finalString = finalString + s.charAt(i);  
            }  
        }  
        return finalString;  
    }

    private static boolean isVowel(char c) {  
        String vowels = "aeiou";   
        for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {   
            if (c == vowels.charAt(i))  
                return true;  
        }  
        return false;     
    }  
}
```